# Populating a Table with an Immense Array

Tags: php, mysql, database, arrays, insert

I'm trying to populate a table with content that I've scraped from a page. Problem is, nearly two hundred thousand items are being inserted at the same time, breaking the system. I get the errors:

> Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: MySQL server has gone away in C:\xampp\htdocs\testing\scrabble2.php on line 15
>
> Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: Error reading result set's header in C:\xampp\htdocs\testing\scrabble2.php on line 15
>
> Could not add item: MySQL server has gone away

```
<?
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load_file('http://kisa.ca/scrabble/');
$collection = $html->find('.words');
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","root") or die('Could not connect: ' .    mysql_error());
mysql_select_db( 'test' ) or die('Could not select database: ' . mysql_error());
foreach ($collection as $word)
{
    $add_item = "INSERT INTO ScrabbleWords (ID, Words) VALUES ('', '" . $word . "')";
    mysql_query($add_item) or die('Could not add item: ' . mysql_error());
    echo $word;
    echo ", ";
}
echo "Done";
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

So how can I populate my table with such a large array?

Comment: As soon as I read the question and the word "ScrabbleWords" I laughed haha.

Comment: MySQL server shouldn't just 'go away' - check the log output for mysql_error... can be found (by default) in /var/log/mysql/mysql_error

Comment: If you just want the scrabble word list so you can load it locally with LOAD DATA you can get them here: http://www.edcollins.com/jamble/ or http://www.isc.ro/lists/twl06.zip

Answer (score 1):

Use MySQL `extended inserts`, which will greatly reduce the number of queries:

```
INSERT INTO ScrabbleWords (ID, Words) VALUES ('', 'Word1'), ('', 'Word2'), ('', 'Word3'), ...;
```

You can loop through and group together say 1000 words into one insert at a time.

You can also increase the MySQL connection timeout:

```
ini_set('mysql.connect_timeout', 300); // seconds
ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 300);
```

Comment: This suggestion will take you from 200,000 INSERT statements to 200 insert statements (assuming you do 1000 words at a time)

Comment: It seems this would be the most elegant answer if I knew what you meant. Forgive my ignorance, my quest is sincere. How would one go about looping the grouping of these words? After I group them, each group is stored in a variable? What are the values of 'Word1', 'Word2', etc. in your example?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use insert like this:

```
INSERT INTO example
    VALUES
  (100, 'Name 1', 'Value 1', 'Other 1'),
  (101, 'Name 2', 'Value 2', 'Other 2'),
  (102, 'Name 3', 'Value 3', 'Other 3'),
  (103, 'Name 4', 'Value 4', 'Other 4');
```

Answer (score 0):

Why does MySQL server goes away.

> You can get these errors if you send a query to the server that is incorrect or too large. If **mysqld** receives a packet that is too large or out of order, it assumes that something has gone wrong with the client and closes the connection. If you need big queries (for example, if you are working with big BLOB columns), you can increase the query limit by setting the server's `max_allowed_packet` variable, which has a default value of **1MB**. You may also need to increase the maximum packet size on the client end. More information on setting the packet size is given in Section `C.5.2.10`, **“Packet too large”**.

[Source link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/gone-away.html)

This may or may not be the answer to you problem, but I think this was the most probable reason.